# How do I redirect the sql statements in Rails to other than log/development.log?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

Something in Rails (ActiveRecord::Base.logger ?) puts all executed SQL into log/development.log.

I have a rails app, whose data is populated by several rake tasks. Often in development, I want to run the web app, and run several of these rake tasks simultaneously (they are long running tasks that talk to other systems and create data in a local database).

Annoyingly, they all log to the same file at the same time.

How/where should I change this? Can I do it from the command line? Where (if in a rake file) should I do it? Or should I create new environments for each rake task?

Is there documentation i should have read to answer this, where is it?

Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My current solution is

```
dec "update statistics"
task :update_stats => :environment do

     root_path = Rails.configuration.root_path
     env = Rails.configuration.environment
     ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(File.join(root_path, "log", "#{env}-stats.log"))
     #code ...

end
```

It feels a bit hacky, but maybe that's just the way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Depends on what you are really trying to log. In Rails 3.+ you can use the `ActiveSupport::LogSubscriber` mechanism to hook into Rails internals and log certain interests to other files.

If you really want to hijack the core `Rails.logger` instance for each of your rake tasks, than do just that.

```
  # lib/tasks/foo.rake

  desc "Prints Hello World"
  task :helloworld do
     Rails.logger = Logger.new("/path/to/hello-world.log")
     # do something in your Rails stack that would write to "Rails.logger"
  end
```

Not tested, but I think that might work.

That being said, I think subscribing to interesting events in ActiveRecord via `ActiveSupport::LogSubscriber` might be a cleaner approach

Comment: Thanks. The project is on Rails 2.3.11. I have posted my own current solution as a possible answer. You can see that `ActiveRecord::Base.logger` is a consideration independent of `Rails.logger`.

Comment: Also, I get `NoMethodError: undefined method 'logger=' for Rails:Module` if I do  `Rails.logger = ...` instead of `ActiveRecord::Base.logger = ...`